# How do you use a C++ iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have a vector like so:

`vector<MyType*> _types;`

And I want to iterate over the vector and call a function on each of MyTypes in the vector, but I'm getting invalid return errors from the compiler. It appears the `pos` iterator isn't a pointer to MyType, it's something else. What am I not understanding?

Edit: Some code..

```
    for (pos = _types.begin(); pos < _types.end(); pos++)
{
    InternalType* inst = *pos->GetInternalType();
}
```

The compiler errors are:

- invalid return type 'InternalType**' for overloaded 'operator ->'
- 'GetInternalType' : is not a member of 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>'

**Edit pt2**

Should my vector contain pointers or objects?  What are the pros and cons? If I am using `new` to create an instance, I am guessing I can only use a vector of pointers to MyType is that correct?

Comment: Hard to tell you what you're not understanding when you haven't even shown us what you've tried ;)

Comment: (*pos)->GetInternalType()

Comment: "Should my vector contain pointers or objects?". If it contains objects, then objects which you add to the vector will be *copied* into the vector. Changes to the objects in the vector will not affect the originals. So it depends whether that's what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the vector contained objects, not pointers, you could do `pos->foo()`.  The iterator "acts like" a pointer.  But your vector contains pointers, so an iterator will act like a pointer to a pointer, so needs to be dereferenced twice.

```
MyType *pMyType = *pos; // first dereference
if (pMyType) {          // make sure the pointer is not null
  pMyType->foo();       // second dereference
}
```

If you are sure the pointer is not null, you could do this:

```
(*pos)->foo();
```

The parenthesis around `*pos` are needed so the dereference applies to `pos`, not to `pos->foo()`.  Order of operations.

If your vector needs to contain items from a class hierarchy (e.g., subclasses of MyType), then you have to make it a vector of pointers.  Otherwise a vector of objects is probably simpler.

Comment: thanks dan, everything i needed here, especially the tip on class hierarchies :)

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `_types` as a vector of pointers. Assuming your `pos` is an iterator into that vector, it's going to be an iterator to a pointer, so you'll need to dereference it *twice* to get to an instance of `MyType`.

Edit: based on what you've added to the question: You have something like `*pos->whatever`. Try `(*pos)->whatever` instead. As it stands, you're trying to use `whatever` as a member of the iterator, then dereference the result...

Answer (score 1):

Iterators are not pointers. Iterators are types that behave like pointers. In some implementations of some containers, the iterator type may in fact be a pointer (all pointers are iterators), but this cannot be used as a general rule.

If you need to generate a pointer from an iterator, you can use `&*pos`, which will dereference the iterator and then get the address of the result (of course, this doesn't work if unary `operator &` is overloaded, but that's a whole other can of worms).

Answer (score 0):

```
for (vector<MyType*>::iterator i = _tpes.begin(); i != _types.end(); ++i) {
  // do something with i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (vector<MyType*>::iterator it = _types.begin();
     it != _types.end();
     ++it)
{
    // `*it` is this iteration's `MyType*` from your vector
}
```